# How to specify 2 différents source for a same package when in prod or in dev when using poetry?

Tags: python-poetry

I am using Python / Poetry to manage my virtual environment.
I would like to install `django-listing` from pypi when in production but use a local version of `django-listing` when developping, so I wrote this `pyproject.toml` file :

```
[tool.poetry]
...

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11"
Django = "^4.1.7"
...

[tool.poetry.group.prod]
optional = true

[tool.poetry.group.prod.dependencies]
django-listing = "^0.0.15"

[tool.poetry.group.dev]
optional = true

[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
django-listing = {path = "../django-listing", develop = true}

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"
```

When I do :

```
poetry install --with prod --without dev
```

It is always the develop version of django-listing that is used : why ?
This is the same thing if I clear caches and if I remove/re-create the environment : how can I proceed ?
I am using Poetry 1.4 and python 3.11

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to specify the same package in multiple groups. All the packages are required to be compatible to each other even if they are sitting in different groups, as specified in https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/managing-dependencies/. And 2 packages sharing the name are incompatible.
You can try using environment markers (https://python-poetry.org/docs/master/dependency-specification#using-environment-markers).

Answer (score -2):

As answered on github, poetry 1.4 reads all dependencies regardless they are in a group or not. So it is not possible to declare a package twice with 2 different sources.

Comment: I recommend you edit your answer to provide the link to the GitHub discussion.